# django admin page dropdown foreign key

Tags: django

I have to classes in different models.
first one, called Audiobook

```
from django.db import models
from labels.models import Label


class Audiobook(models.Model):
    """the audiobook object"""
    title = models.TextField()
    content = models.TextField()
    cover = models.FilePathField()
    playtime = models.TextField()
    moneyLink = models.TextField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    label = models.ForeignKey(Label)
```

the second one, called Label

```
from django.db import models


class Label(models.Model):
    """the label object"""
    name = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In Audiobooks I have a ForeignKey on a Label object.

Now the admin classes.

audiobook_admin:

```
from audiobooks.models import Audiobook
from labels.models import Label
from django.contrib import admin


class LabelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Label


class AudiobookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['title']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['content']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['cover']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['playtime']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['moneyLink']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['status']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['label']})
    ]
    inlines = [LabelInline]

admin.site.register(Audiobook, AudiobookAdmin)
```

The label admin class:

```
from labels.models import Label
from django.contrib import admin


class LabelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['name']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['description']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['status']})
    ]

admin.site.register(Label, LabelAdmin)
```

With the Label part all fine.

What I must do to can select a Label in the Audiobook admin page with a Dropdown control?
If I wont to enter a new Audiobook I the following error:

```
Exception Value: <class 'labels.models.Label'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'audiobooks.models.Audiobook'>
```

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dropdown control is the default one for ForeignKey.

Default admin configuration should work :

```
from labels.models import Label
from audiobooks.models import Audiobook
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Label)
admin.site.register(Audiobook)
```